# How to assign values to a variable iteratively using for loop in maxima?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, maxima

I am using for loop to assign values to a variable, more precisely a matrix, in xmaxima. The values seem to get stored in the individual indices but I am unable to recall the entire matrix values by calling the matrix variable name.

For example:

Suppose I am assigning `xreal[1]=5; xreal[2]=6;...... xreal[5]=9`. I want xreal to have `[5 6 7 8 9]`, which is not happening.

Below is my code. What's the right way to do this?

```
k:1;
for i from 1 thru length(xvals) do (
(if(imagpart(xvals[i]) = 0) then xreal[k]:xvals[i]),k:k+1
);
```

Here,

```
xreal[1]; gives 0.06111
xreal[2]; gives 0.080 and so on.
```

But `xreal` just gives "xreal" i.e. the variable name itself.

Answer (score 1):

You must simply initialize the matrix first.

Example:

```
(%i1)  m:zeromatrix(1,3);
(%o1)  [0 0 0]

(%i2)  for i from 1 thru 3 do (
       m[1,i]: i);
       m;
(%o2)  [1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler way.

makelist( if imagpart(xvals[s])  =0.....  , i,1, length(xvals))